# SQL - Creating hierarchy in PARTITION BY statement

Tags: sql, oracle, window-functions

I am using the following code to match rows by ID number:

```
SELECT *,
    LEAD(ORDER, 1) OVER(PARTITION BY ID_NBR) AS PREV_ORDER
FROM TABLE
```

In my data, some ID numbers are missing. If (and only if) an ID number is missing, I would like to match the rows by Cust_Name. Is this possible with the LEAD/OVER commands?

Thanks,

Comment: missing, you mean they are NULL?

Comment: The ID_NBR field is blank.

Comment: Can you define "match"? What is a `cust_name`? Where does the column `order` come into this? You know `order` is an illegal column name unquoted as you have it? It might make things easier if you posted a sample of your original data and then another sample of the data you want together with a full, logical, description of how one got transformed into the other.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need something like this?

```
with tab as (
select 1 id, 'n1' cust_name from dual
union all select 2, 'n2' from dual
union all select null, 'n3' from dual
union all select 4, 'n4' from dual
)
select id, cust_name, 
           lag(cust_name ignore nulls) over(order by id) prev_name,
           lead(cust_name ignore nulls) over(order by id) next_name
from tab;
```

IGNORE NULLS - skips NULL values when looking for lag/lead values.

You may add "PARTITION BY col[,col]" before ORDER BY

It's essential to have ORDER BY with LAG / LEAD functions